# Put Components into a list or array?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

how can I collect the name of all of my Script(Generic)  (in a list or array?)
Like below?

```
public class inputdata
    {
        public Component com;
        public int index;

        public inputdata(Component newcom,int newindex)
        {
            com = newcom;
            index = newindex;
        }
    }
```

```
inputdata[] data = {new inputdata(component1, 1),inputdata(component2, 1),inputdata(component3, 1)}

foreach (inputdata ft in data)
{
movefunc <ft.com> (ft.index);
}
```

```
void movefunc <T> (int index){
  gameobject.GetComponent<T>()
}
```

it 's shows 'component1' is a type, which is not valid in the given context.

component1 is my c# script, I use it for detecting raycast.

like this

```
hitInfo.collider.gameObject.GetComponent <component1 > ()
```

Comment: Not quite sure what you want to achieve, could you be more specific? If you have a list of `inputdata` objects you could always use a for-loop and just grab `inputdata.com.Name`

Comment: @Lightvvind
I wanna create an array or list to collect all my Component(Generic type), is that a way to do it?

Comment: I still don't understand what name you want to get? I don't see a name property anywhere? But if you just want a List of inputdata your edit is totally correct

Comment: Can you provide a minimal working example to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Can you show how/where component1 is defined?

Comment: where do `component1` etc come from? Sounds like you already **have** references to components ... then why use `GetComponent`(s) at all?

Comment: so `component1` is the **`Type`** of your component, not a `Component` reference right? ... what are you going to do with it within `movefunc` ? do you actually need the reference to the component or is all you want to do check if it exists?

Answer (score 0):

It seems not clear what you are trying to achieve. In case it helps you can achive a list of the components in a gameObject like this:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

public class GetComponets : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject goWithComponets; //attach in the inspector

    void Start() {
        getComponets().ToList().ForEach(component => {
            Debug.Log(component.GetType().ToString());
        });
    }

    private IEnumerable<Component> getComponets() {
        return goWithComponets.GetComponents<Component>().ToList(); ;  
    }
}
```

Your components wont be generic, they for sure will inherit from the `Component` type, so in case its needed you can grab all the components from the gameObject getting all the components from the base class `Component`, and if you need to handle specifics types, handle that later on with some code.

Comment: I m not using the one type of component, it's like script .gameobject.GetComponent<T>()

Comment: @feinathanlin your class stores a `Component` reference ... so what hinders you from using `GetComponents<Component>()`?

Comment: @derHugo
 component1 is my c# script, I use it for detecting raycast.

like this

hitInfo.collider.gameObject.GetComponent <component1 > ()

Comment: so `component1` is the **`Type`** of your component, not a `Component` reference right?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you don't want a generic but rather something like e.g

```
public class inputdata
{
    public Type Type;
    public int Index;

    public inputdata(Type type, int index)
    {
        Type = type;
        Index = index;
    }
}

inputdata[] data = new []
{
    new inputdata(typeof(component1), 1),
    new inputdata(typeof(component2), 1),
    new inputdata(typeof(component3), 1)
};
```

and then

```
foreach (inputdata ft in data)
{
    movefunc (ft.type, ft.index);
}
```

and

```
void movefunc (Type type, int index)
{
    // ... whatever happens before and where you get the hitInfo from

    if(hitInfo.collider.TryGetComponent(type, out var component))
    {
        // component of given type exists on the hit object
        // "component" will contain a reference to it in the base type "Component" -> if you need it in its actual type you will need to cast
    }
    else
    {
        // there is no component of given type on the hit object
    }
}
```